# ¿Cómo hago para duplicar cada elemento impar en una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mi idea es tener una lista como por ejemplo `[1,2,3,4,5]` y cambiarla a `[2,2,6,4,10]`, pero solo logro hacer el código para que duplique todos los números de la lista. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
def function(n):
   lst=[]
   for x in str(n):
      lst.append(x)
   lst=list(map(int,lst))
   lst=list(map(lambda x:x*2,lst))
   print(lst)
```

PD: Cuando digo elemento impar me refiero a los números en las posiciones impares, no a si el número en sí mismo es o no impar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola!

A mi se me ocurrió definir la siguiente función, donde dada una lista multiplica la i-ésima entrada impar por una constante 2:

```
def impares(L):
    for i in range(0,len(L)):
        if L[i]%2 != 0:
            L[i]=2*L[i]
    return L
```

Así dada L =[1,2,3,4,5], si aplico impares(L), obtengo:

```
[2, 2, 6, 4, 5]
```

Esta es una propuesta sencilla de visualizar y puedo cambiar las i-ésimas entradas impares por pares, modificando la tercera linea del código:

```
 if L[i]%2 == 0:
```

Comment: Está muy bueno ese código y de hecho si es fácil de entender,además es útil cuando la lista ya contiene elementos,te felicito

Comment: Gracias! podrías darle palomita :)

Answer (score 4):

Debes comprobar la paridad o no del índice de cada elemento. Una opción muy simple es usar `enumerate` (que nos retorna parejas `(indice, valor)` y el operador módulo (resto de la división entera) para ver si el índice es o no par:

```
def function(l):
    lst = []
    for i, n in enumerate(l):
        if not i % 2:
            lst.append(n*2)
        else:
            lst.append(n)
    return lst
```

O usando una listas por compresión:

```
def function(l):
    return [n if i % 2 else n*2 for i, n in enumerate(l)]
```

La salida sería:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> print(function(l))
[2, 2, 6, 4, 10]
```

Si se quiere hacer sobre la propia lista en vez de retornar una nueva es más eficiente en este caso usar `range` e iterar solo sobre los índices pares usando el parámetro `step` del mismo:

```
def function(l):
    for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
        l[i] *= 2
```

En este caso:

```
>>> lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> function(lista)
>>> print(lista)
[2, 2, 6, 4, 10]
```

Si quisiéramos iterar sobre los índices impares simplemente hacemos `range(1, len(l), 2)`.

---

Si a la función le pasas un entero y quieres multiplicar por 2 los dígitos en posiciones impares puedes hacer lo mismo con el casting adecuado:

```
def function(n):
    return [int(d) if i % 2 else int(d)*2 for i, d in enumerate(str(n))]
```

La salida es:

```
>>> print(function(12345))
[2, 2, 6, 4, 10]
```

> **Nota:** En Python el indexado es base 0, es decir, el primer índice del iterable es el 0, no el 1.

Comment: Gracias, voy a estudiar eso de enumerate ya que es la primera vez que lo veo.

Comment: En la primer opción de código,veo que no agregaste valores a la lista hasta después del enumerate, se podría usar enumerate para duplicar cada elemento par cuando ya la lista tiene valores

Comment: @Felka98 no entiendo muy bien a que te refieres, `enumerate` no difiere mucho del `for in l`, simplemente nos va retornando tuplas `(indice, item)` en vez de solo el item. `lst` es una lista vacía al igual que en tu ejemplo, si esta lista tuviera algún contenido inicial no importa ya que `enumerate` itera sobre `l`, no le importa para nada `lst`. Si te refieres a modificar `l` directamente en vez de retornar otra lista, en este caso sería más simple y eficiente usar indexado con `range`(he editado la pregunta añadiendo un ejemplo)

Comment: Eso si, en un ciclo `for in` (lo que se extiende para `enumerate`) **nunca debes agregar o eliminar elementos a la lista sobre la que se itera** o tendrás sorpresas. Si puedes modificar el elemento si es mutable sin problemas, pero no cambiar el tamaño de la lista durante el `for`.

Comment: Ya entendí, no sabía que enumerate iteraba sobre "l" y no sobre "lst". Gracias por la ayuda